# Is there a way to clean this code up? It functions, but it's hacked together and ugly

Tags: javascript, foreach

Looking for a cleaner way to write this for loop. I was going to use continue; and realized after the fact that .forEach doesn't like that syntax.

```
const findNoOptions = array => {
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 1; ; i += 1) {
    str = "Z".repeat(i);
    let found = false;
    array.forEach(element => {
      if (element.toUpperCase().includes(str)) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if (!found) {
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: use some() or every() to avoid un-needed iterations and the kickstand var, _found_.

Comment: Please post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Use `.some`? Also, if a string has any amount of `Z` then by definition it has one `Z`, so the `for` loop is not very useful.

Comment: Also, the function doesn't return anything. Calling it will at best just finish and you wouldn't know it succeeds or it will run into an infinite loop.

Comment: You're breaking out of loop just after first iteration, is it intentional ?  if yes than you don't need for loop

Comment: Sorry, this is for automated testing and I'm checking to see when a user passes text into a dropdown that if they enter something that isn't there it will return "No options".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that

```js
const findNoOptions = array => {
  let str = "";
  while(true) {
    str += "Z";
    let found = array.some(el => el.toUpperCase().includes(str))
    if (!found) break;
  }
};
```

Comment: The loop is probably superfluous. Either that or harmful - it will either be executed once or infinite times.

Comment: The loop is for increasing the `str` with one `'Z'` per iteration. It will break as soon as the array DOES NOT contain `str`. So for `['foz', 'barzz']` = it will break in the second iteration. There is no case of infinite, because there is no infinite strings in javascript.

Comment: OK true but it's still superfluous: `"ZZZ".includes("Z"):` will be `true` as would `"ZZZ".includes("ZZ"):` and `"ZZZ".includes("ZZZ"):`. There is no need for multiple checks

Comment: @Avraham, this is what I was looking to do. I was just looking into using the .some when I saw you posted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a break you could do

```
const findNoOptions = array => {
  let str = "";
  while(array.some(el => el.toUpperCase().includes(str))) {
    str += "Z";
  }
};
```